# How properly add MenuItem to Select?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rxjs

I have this code:
For some reasons after this, my Select have no choices. Looks like nothing returned, but it is not it is.
If i put just random MenuItem with static data, it works properly, but it is not that i need.

```
interface LoaderSelectorProps<T> {
    settings: { m: number, width: number },
    data: T,
    className: string,
}

export default function LoaderSelector<T extends LoaderSelectorTypes>(props: LoaderSelectorProps<T>) {
    const data = props.data;
    return (
        <div className={props.className}>
            <FormControl sx={props.settings}>
                <InputLabel id={props.className}>{props.className}</InputLabel>
                <Select labelId={props.className} label={props.className}>
                        {switchType(data)}
                </Select>
            </FormControl>
        </div>
    )
}



function switchType<T extends LoaderSelectorTypes>(data: T): ReactNode {
    switch (interfaceMatcher(data)) {
        case InterfaceMatcher.ProviderArray: {
            (data as MapProvider[]).map(provider => {
                return <MenuItem key={provider.name} value={provider.name}>{provider.name}</MenuItem>
            });
            break;
        }
        case InterfaceMatcher.MapTypeArray: {
            (data as MapType[]).map(type => {
                return <MenuItem key={type.id} value={type.id}>{type.name}</MenuItem>
            });
            break;
        }
        case InterfaceMatcher.MapArray: {
            (data as Map[]).map(map => {
                return <MenuItem key={map.id} value={map.id}>{map.name}</MenuItem>
            });
            break;
        }
        case InterfaceMatcher.ZoomArray: {
            (data as ZoomLevelRatioSize[]).map(zoom => {
                return <MenuItem key={zoom.width} value={zoom.width}> </MenuItem>
            });
            break;
        }
    }
    throw "No data";
}
```

I did nothing yet :)

UPD: If create Array of ReactNode and push all of MenuItem's to array and then return from function this array - it works.

```js
 let a: Array<ReactNode> = [];
    switch (interfaceMatcher(data)) {
        case InterfaceMatcher.ProviderArray: {
            (data as MapProvider[]).map(provider => {
                a.push(<MenuItem key={provider.name} value={provider.name}>{provider.name}</MenuItem>)
            });
            return a;
        }
        case InterfaceMatcher.MapTypeArray: {
            (data as MapType[]).map(type => {
                a.push(<MenuItem key={type.id} value={type.id}>{type.name}</MenuItem>)
            });
            return;
        }
```

Comment: can you provide what `switchType` returns when you use the component **without** static data?

Comment: @LucasA it is returned array of objects like [{ id:0, name: "xam"}, {id:1, name:"ginfo"}]